# Run void on launch from another class

Tags: iphone, xcode, latitude-longitude, void

I can't reference this in any way and get the void to run.
I can run the void in any other class just making a function and calling it but in this class there's no view did load. So the Q is, how do I run it?

I've tried referencing the variables from the other class but it gives compiler errors.

The return values from getCoords must be in the type double because it's coordinates.

```
#import "OmarAnnotation.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
#import <netdb.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"



@implementation SFAnnotation

@synthesize image;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize string;




+(void) getCoords {
NSString *string = @"http://jerwuqu.info/iambored/?GETPOS";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSString *otherURLContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(otherURLContents);

NSArray* foo = [otherURLContents componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
NSString *longi = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *lati = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];
NSLog(longi);
NSLog(lati);

double latiDouble = [lati doubleValue];
double longiDouble = [longi doubleValue];

}


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
 double extern *latiDouble;
 double extern *longiDouble;


CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
theCoordinate.latitude  = latiDouble;
theCoordinate.longitude = longiDouble;
return theCoordinate;

}


- (void)dealloc
{
[image release];
[super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *)title
{
return @"Omar";
}

// optional
- (NSString *)subtitle
{



return @"Ortdenhegen";

}


@end
```

//This is my viewDidLoad in the other class file

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
     self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;   //Satelite?       
     self.mapAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
     SFAnnotation *sfAnnotation = [[SFAnnotation alloc] init];
     [self.mapAnnotations insertObject:sfAnnotation atIndex:0];
     [SFAnnotation getCoords]; // <- The line with an error
     [self cityAction:self];
     [self gotoLocation];
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other class you're calling from, write `[sfAnnotation whateverMethodYouWantToCall];`

In example if you want to call `getCoords` from the other class's viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //Whatever code you have before.
    [sfAnnotation getCoords];
    //Whatever code you have after.
}
```

Comment: Didn't work :( getting lldb error without any error messages.
Posting viewDidLoad above.

Comment: Ohh, my bad... You should be using `sfAnnotation`(your variable, not the class). In other words `[sfAnnotation getCoords];` Editing the original post.